# Why was my question deleted?

Tags: discussion

I recently posted [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/150720/why-are-microtransactions-more-or-less-universally-hated) that attracted a lot of attention. Now, 20 minutes ago, [Alexandre Vaillancourt](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/40264/alexandre-vaillancourt) deleted my question after it being put on hold. I do not understand why it was worth deleting so now I wonder - **Why was it deleted**? How can I edit the post to make it worth un-deleting? A direct response would be great if you read this Alexandre so I can understand your reasoning! :)

Comment: Seems like he judged the question as too much opinion based.

Comment: @Eldy Yes, it definitely was. That's why it was closed. Not why it was initially deleted though, as noted below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you for asking this on Meta.

Your question was closed mainly because it was attracting opinions rather than facts. Questions that do not involve programming often hit the HNQ, attracting all sorts of users. This particular question hit a raw nerve upon users who visit the site (StackExchange in general); it unfortunately gave them the option to voice their opinion and show their disagreement, and they forgot that voicing their opinion that way is not the expected practice on most of StackExchange sites.

Additionally, the question had already 3 close votes on it. Since @DMGregory and I have been elected as moderator last week, we’ve kind of refrained on using our user rights to vote to close questions because moderator votes are binding (one moderator vote closes the question); as such, if the question had been posted one week before, it would have been closed by the community much earlier.

Your question was deleted because it attracted *a lot* of these visitors each contributing their two cents without really reading what was already there, and we felt that the reputation given out was not representative of what this site is about.

Unfortunately, there is not much to be done to the question, as the issue here is mainly with the answers.

We’ve decided to un-delete it and historically lock it. The question will be available to be seen by visitors, users will have their reputation back, but no further actions will be doable on the question and its answers.

Comment: It's a shame that bad answers, or even badly voted-on answers can close something that might have been salvageable on microtransactions as a design decision (with some re-wording). I liked at least one of the answers there because it did a decent job of sourcing its claims. But it's understandable that the end result is a poor reflection of the purpose of this community, and so it was closed.